# SCOPE_IDENTITY() return NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 express, below is the SP, who return

> (0 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 515, Level
> 16, State 2, Procedure
> sp_AddCarrierFees,
>
> Line 21 Cannot
> insert the value NULL into column
> 'attribute_value_id', table
> 'MyDevSystem.dbo.shipping_fees';
>
> column
> does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

And this is the SP :

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddCarrierFees]
    @carrier_id INT,
    @zone_id INT,
    @attribute_value_id INT,
    @attribute_title varchar(20),
    @fees decimal(6,2)
AS
BEGIN
    if @attribute_value_id = 0 begin 
        insert into shipping_attribute_value (attribute_id,attribute_value,sort_order) 
        select attribute_id, @fees,0 from shipping_attribute where carrier_id=@carrier_id and attribute_title=@attribute_title; 
        
        declare @NewID int;
        set @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
        print @NewID;
        
        insert into shipping_fees (zone_id, attribute_value_id) values (@zone_id, @NewID); 
    end 
    else 
    begin 
        update shipping_attribute_value set attribute_value=@fees where attribute_value_id=@attribute_value_id;
    end
END
```

Any people know why? I have read many post in StackOverFlow, but still not find solution.Somebody say use @@IDENTITY or IDENT_CURRENT instead, but it possible got the identity who made by other users.

**FIXED:I found the reason, because the first insert statement is fail, so why return (0 row(s) affected) , after i fix that insert statement,it works now. thanks you for everyone.**

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `shipping_attribute_value` table?

Comment: Yes, 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[shipping_attribute_value](
 [attribute_value_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [attribute_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [attribute_value] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [sort_order] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_shipping_attribute_value] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [attribute_value_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: The attribute_value_id is primary_key and auto-increment by 1

Answer (score 1):

First verify that the `shipping_attribute_value` actually has an `identity` column.  Without an identity column, `scope_identity()` doesn't work.

EDIT: I missed that the `insert` is actually using the `select`, but marc_s noticed it :)  *grabs coffee*

How about doing a separate select just to see the output:

```
select attribute_id, @fees,0 from shipping_attribute 
       where carrier_id=@carrier_id and attribute_title=@attribute_title; 

insert into shipping_attribute_value (attribute_id,attribute_value,sort_order) 
    select attribute_id, @fees,0 from shipping_attribute 
    where carrier_id=@carrier_id and attribute_title=@attribute_title;
```

If no rows are inserted, `scope_identity()` should be null :)